# geometric intuition for A and A-transpose having the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that $A$ and $A^t$ have the same characteristic polynomial. But I'm looking for some picture of why they should have the same set of eigenvalues.

Maybe slightly more concrete question is whether or not you can say something about bases of $A^t$ given an eigenbasis of $A$. Does knowing one give you a computational advantage in computing the other? On one hand, they seem unrelated. On the other hand, if you know the standard basis is an eigenbasis of $A$, then the standard basis is forced to be eigen w.r.t. $A^t$.

Insights or references for either of these questions would be appreciated.

Comment: It is clear ir you consider that $A^t$ is the matrix of the dual linear map.

Comment: You can reduce this to the same question about the null spaces and bases for the null spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $v_j$ is an eigenbasis of $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_j$, so that $A v_j = \lambda_j v_j$. Then for all dual vectors $f$ we have

$$\langle f, A v_j \rangle = \lambda_j \langle f, v_j \rangle$$

where $\langle -, - \rangle$ denotes the dual pairing. If $f_i$ denotes the dual basis to $v_j$, so that $\langle f_i, v_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$, then we get

$$\langle f_i, A v_j \rangle = \lambda_j \langle f_i, v_j \rangle = \lambda_j \delta_{ij}.$$

Rewriting this as

$$\langle A^{\ast} f_i, v_j \rangle = \lambda_j \delta_{ij}$$

and fixing $i$ and varying over $j$, then varying over $i$, shows that $A^{\ast} f_i = \lambda_i f_i$, hence $f_i$ is an eigenbasis of $A^{\ast}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$.

Comment: What if there is no eigenbasis?

Comment: You can run basically the same argument with the expression $(A - I)^k$ and generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Since you need the eigenvalue in there, I don't quite see it quickly, @Qiaochu.

Comment: Note that, in a generalization of this argument to a non-diagonalizable matrix, if $v_1$ is an eigenvector and $v_2$ is the second vector of a Jordan basis, then their duals swap their roles: $f_2$ is the eigenvector and $f_1$ is the generalized eigenvector. I think that the generalized proof will have to account for this property in some way.